# Performance / issues calling python script to provide json output to ansible

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I have ansible modules, thousands of settings i have to perform, lot of data parsing has to be done to provide valid inputs to ansible modules inputs.

I have opted Python script which perform thousands of settings and it performs data parsing and provide valid json inputs to ansible modules

```
- name: Calling Python1 script
  script: /usr/bin/python /python1.py
  register: var1

#perform few tasks using ansible modules

#Calling python2 script
- name: Calling Python2 script
  script: /usr/bin/python /python2.py
  register: var2


#perform few tasks using ansible modules
```

Python script is calling multiple times at least for every 20 ansible tasks one python script is called to get proper inputs and data parsing.

Everything is working fine and no issues still now.

Anything that is performing in python scripts tasks can be achieved from ansible playbooks also (By using jinja2 templates). But its takes lot of time to Develop and it is quite difficult to write ansible playbooks for data parsing and providing input to ansible modules.

This is the reason, I am using python script and calling python scripts in ansible playbooks.

Now My Concern is,

1. Calling Python scripts have any performance penalty or any issues?
2. Calling Python scripts is a standard coding ? is i am loosing any benefits if i am calling python scripts  like error handlings or controlling ansible playbooks

Comment: Do you have issues with performance?  I'm not understanding what your problem here is.

Comment: No issues still now, I am not seeing any performance issue(I am asking if anything is there if i call python script). I am just thinking is it valid development calling other python scripts i ansible script. when we can achieve in ansible itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Anything that is performing in python scripts tasks can be achieved from ansible playbooks also (By using jinja2 templates). But its takes lot of time to Develop and it is quite difficult to write ansible playbooks for data parsing and providing input to ansible modules.

I think this is what you're really asking for comments on, or restated, "My team can do this all in Ansible+Python, but we could do it in Ansible+Jinja2."

You don't say how complex the Python scripts you're creating are, but one of the big benefits to using Ansible+Jinja is that your playbooks will be more [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-idempotency) and ultimately cause less un-necessary change to the systems (which can result in additional service restarts, management questions, etc).

But balanced with that is how much is the work of building and maintaining these Jinja2 templates going to impact your team?  If you are a small shop and the Ansible is only a small fraction of your work, but you have a substantial depth of Python developers, then the Python script might be the "good enough" solution.

You mentioned two concerns:

> 1. Calling Python scripts have any performance penalty or any issues?

Yes, any time you're calling out to another task (Python, Shell, executable, etc) from Ansible you will have some additional execution penalty.  You might not see it in a small environment, but if you're running the playbook against 100's of systems, or on every container that only lasts for a few minutes then you're bound to see some performance penalties doing it this way.

> 2. Calling Python scripts is a standard coding ? is i am loosing any benefits if i am calling python scripts like error handlings or controlling ansible playbooks

Yes, you're going to have to handle more of the error handling in your Python script that would otherwise be handled for you in the Ansible or Jinja2 coding, including what you mentioned along with the idempotent features Ansible provides.

Ultimately, what you are asking for a "one right answer" and there rarely is one.  On my teams I am trying to build up a depth of Ansible experience so the Ansible+Jinja2 is the route I would choose.

Comment: How about writing own ansible modules, which takes few inputs and process it and provide output to ansible variable.

Comment: I've never written an Ansible module but I would assume it would be a bit quicker since it is executing locally (I believe).

Comment: I have written ansible module just to achieve my requirements and it is easy

Comment: @sagar_dev do can you share the module code so future viewers of this thread might have that to start from?